# Unwrapping optional Value

Tags: swift, option-type

I am trying to parse through an optional value that has these values in it

```
Optional(UITableViewCell: ox7ff2f9cfbc80; frame = (0 0; 414 44); text = 'Clarity'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer:0x7ff2f9cfb250>>)
```

and would like to just grab the text part of 'Clarity' to print out in another line. Please let me know if this is possible as I am new to Swift! Thanks!

Here is How I created the table cells

I have a List of Song Tracks here

```
tracks = [Clarity, Freak-a-Leek, What's My Age Again?, All The Small Things, Bandz A Make Her Dance, Cant Tell Me Nothing, Slow Jamz, Hate It Or Love It, Dark Horse, Teenage Dream, In Too Deep, Just Hold On, We're Going Home, Energy, Fat Lip]
```

and create the tableviewcells by doing the following

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? UITableViewCell

    cell?.textLabel?.text=self.tracks[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}
```

and here is how I get the optional value

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
   let Cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

}
```

Comment: Show us the code how you set your cell.

Comment: Updated it. Apologies for the wait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use optional chaining to reach into the optional to get a specific field, then check if the chain has a value with `if let`:

```
if let txt = optionalCell?.text {
    println(txt)
}
// if you want to, add an else
else {
    // to handle the optional chain being nil
}
```

`optionalCell?.text` means: if `optionalCell` has a value, get the `text` property, else return `nil`.  Then the `if let` “unwraps” the optional, setting `txt` to be a regular value if the optional contains one.  If you want code to handle there not being one, you can add an `else` clause.

If you want to use a default value in case of `nil` (say, an empty string), then there is a shorthand for this:

```
let txt = optionalCell?.text ?? "Blank"
```

`??` takes an optional value on the left, and a default value on the right, and evaluates to either the value in the optional, or the default if it was `nil`.

You might see people recommending using `!` sometimes.  **Do not follow their advice**.  `!` is a “force-unwrap”, and if the optional you unwrap is ever `nil` your program will quit with an assertion.  There are legitimate uses of `!` but they are very rare, much more common is people mis-recommending it when there are better solutions available

Comment: Thank you! This helped out tremendously. I ended up doing if let Cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath){
            println(Cell.textLabel?.text)
        }
and it printed out "Optional('Clarity')" now to get it to print with just Clarity. haha

Comment: Found it! its just 
if let Cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath){ title =Cell.textLabel?.text
println(title!)}

Comment: You’re still using `!` which runs the risk of blowing up on you if the `textLabel` ever returns `nil`.  Try `if let title = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.textLabel?.text { println(title) }`